# Named Subpattern backtracking does not work in PCRE

Tags: regex, pcre

Given the following PCRE regex:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?'pat'a|ab))^(?P>pat)b$
```

I expected that it would match the strings `ab` and `abb`. However, it only matches `ab` (and not `abb`, see https://regex101.com/r/F70wge/1). It seems that the backtracker does not go into the named subpattern.

When inlining the pattern as follows:

```
^(?:a|ab)b$
```

Both strings `ab` and `abb` are matched as expected.

Is it possible to change the regex above (with named pattern) in order to make both strings match without inlining the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation in older versions of PCRE. The only fix I know is upgrading to version 10.30.

http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt:

> ### Version 10.30 14-August-2017
>
> 1. The main interpreter, pcre2_match(), has been refactored into a new version
>      that does not use recursive function calls (and therefore the stack) for
>      remembering backtracking positions. This makes --disable-stack-for-recursion a
>      NOOP. **The new implementation allows backtracking into recursive group calls in
>      patterns, making it more compatible with Perl**, and also fixes some other
>      hard-to-do issues such as #1887 in Bugzilla.

(Emphasis mine.)